# How can I determine in Java JPA code where a query is coming from?

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

Scenario:

I'm using JPA and a MySQL database.  I am seeing odd behavior in my application where a value is being updated unexpectedly in the database.  I'd like to determine where in Java this query is coming from.

I've turned on logging on my MySQL database and I can see the UPDATE query being executed.  How can I determine where this call is originating from in Java?  I'm looking for strategies on how to go about solving this problem.

Comment: Logging would be a possibility. Each method leading to a query should log that it is going to do so and (in short) what kind of query it will request.

Comment: JPA generates updates as a result of changes to Java object attributes (for objects that are tied to the JPA session) and that will be done whenever the session is flushed. If you know the Java field that was sent in the UPDATE, then you could set a watch point on it in your debugger to find out where the field was updated.

Comment: You can register an event listener in JPA. It tells you when persist/update/deletes are going to happen, and hence from where